# 1980s kids TV show or movie that takes place in a junk yard

Tags: story-identification

I need some help to identify a show I remember from my childhood - it's driving me crazy I can't name it!

I have a very clear image in my head of a character from the show but I don't think it was a main character. The actor is on all fours; not hands and knees, hands and feet.  They have wheels at the end of all 4 limbs. I remember the setting as some kind of futuristic junk yard or tip ["dump" for Americans].

I originally thought it was a TV show, but the more I've thought about it, I think the image in my mind is from a sticker, which suggests I had an album, so maybe it was a film.

For reference, I was born in 1976 and I think this was when I was around 7 years old.

Comment: Could the setting have been post-apocalyptic ruins rather than a junkyard? In [*Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future) (1987-1988), one of the secondary villains (Blastarr) is a bipedal robot with wheels on his legs (but not on his arms).

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like [Return to Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Oz) from 1985.  The character you refer to is a [Wheeler](https://oz.fandom.com/wiki/Wheelers).

[image]

Comment: Nice catch. Cate, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and evildemonic with some reputation :)

Comment: Perfect. That is the very picture in my mind. Thank you! You are a legend and a gentleman.